# Suppose a composition $g\circ f$ that is injective. Prove $f$ is too.

Tags: functions

> Suppose $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ are two maps such that the composition $g\circ f$ is injective. Prove $f$ is too.

If $g\circ f$ is injective then $(g\circ f)(a_1)=(g\circ f)(a_2)\implies f(a_1)=f(a_2)$, which proves that $g$ is injective.

But I have a problem trying to prove $f$ is injective.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that $g$ is injective if $g\circ f$ is injective by the way. And for the proof try contradiction??

Comment: Assume $f$ is not injective and immediately get a contraddiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f(x) = f(y)$.
Then apply $g$, you get $g(f(x)) = g(f(y))$.
Since $g\circ f$ is injective, you get $x=y$.

Hence we proved that $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$ which is the definition of injectivity.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Use contrapositive:

> If $f$ is not injective, $g\circ f$ can't be injective.