# If $f\circ g$ is $"1-1"$ then show that $g$ is $"1-1"$ and more

Tags: functions

> Let the functions $f,g$ with domain:$\mathbb R$. The function of the composition $f\circ g$ is $"1-1"$.
>
> **I)** Show that $g$ is $"1-1".$
>
> **II)** Show that the equation $g(f(x)+x^3-x)=g(f(x)+2x-1)$ has got exactly 2 positive and one positive roots.

**Personal work:**

**I)** All I can recall regarding the composition is this:
The domain of $f\circ g$ is:

$x\in D_g$ and $g(x)\in D_f$.

**II)** $$g(f(x)+x^3-x)=g(f(x)+2x-1) \iff{g:"1-1"} f(x)+x^3-x=f(x)+2x-1 \iff x^3-3x+1=0$$ and I can't seem to find any obvious roots...

Comment: "exactly 2 positive and one positive roots" Should one of the "positive"s be "negative"? Also, note that you're not asked to _find_ the roots. Only prove they exist and have the sign we want.

Comment: Part I is classic.  It can be found in many textbooks.  Here's [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2165228/290189).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\neq x'$. If $g(x)$ were equal $g(x')$ then $f[g(x)]=f[g(x')]$, a contradiction. So $g(x)\neq g(x')$. This deals with I.

For II, use I: $g[f(x)+x^3-x]=g[f(x)+2x-1]$ implies 
$$
f(x)+x^3-x=f(x)+2x-1\iff x^3-3x+1=0
$$
Now, let $h(x)=x^3-3x+1$. Check:
$$
h(-2)<0,\quad h(-1)>0,\quad h(0)>0,\quad h(1)<0,\quad h(2)>0.
$$ 
So $h$ has 3 zeros: one in $(-2,-1)$, one in $(0,1)$, and the last one in $(1,2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas for you (fill in details):

$$(I)\;\;g(x)=g(y)\implies (f\circ g)(x)=(f\circ g)(y)\implies x=y$$

and now

$$(II)\;\;g(f(x)+x^3-x)=g(f(x)+2x-1)\stackrel{\text{by}\;(I)}\implies f(x)+x^3-x=f(x)+2x-1\implies$$

$$h(x):=x^3-3x+1=0$$

But

$$h(-2)<0\;,\;\;h(0)>0\;,\;\;h(1)<0\;,\;\;h(2)>0\;\ldots$$