# When is composition of linear maps an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, homological-algebra

Let $T:V\rightarrow W$ and $L:W\rightarrow U$ be linear maps between finite-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces.  I'm curious to know when $L\circ T:V\rightarrow U$ is an isomorphism.

My hypothesis is that $L\circ T$ is an isomorphism if and only if $Ker(L)^{\perp} = Im(T)$. (By this I mean that $Im(L) \cap Ker(L)={0}$).

Here's what I've gotten far, by [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2165228/suppose-a-composition-g-circ-f-that-is-injective-prove-f-is-too?rq=1) we know that $L$ must be injective and (arguing dually) we find that $T$ must be surjective.  So, applying the [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma): we write $W\cong V\oplus U$.  Since $T$ is injective and linear then $V\cong Im(T)$.  Now, since $L$ is surjective then if $Im(T)$ intersects $\ker(L)$ non-trivially (ie more than just at $0$) then $Im(L)$ is of strictly lower dimension than $U$; whence it cannot be surjective.  Therefore, $Im(T)\cap \ker(L)={0}$.  The converse direction is clear.

Would my argument also hold if $L\circ T$ is only injective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splitting lemma does not apply in this situation. Also for $L \circ T$ to be bijective $L$ must be surjective and $T$ injective.

The following statement is true for all composition of maps.
$L \circ T$ is bijective iff $T$ is injective and $L|_{im T} $ is bijective.
When looking at linear maps this translates to:

$L \circ T$ is bijective iff $T$ is injective, $L$ surjective and $im(T) \cap ker(L) = {0}$

Comment: Do you have a reference to the second statement (concerning $L|_{imT}$)?  Also, I think the last statement should rather be $im(L)\cap ker(T)=(0)$; right?

Comment: With $T, L$ as given the injectivity of $L \circ 
 T$ can only go wrong on $L|_{im T} $.

Comment: Fair but since $T$ and $L$ are linear then $0\in Im(L)$ and $0\in ker(T)$ so the last statement should be changed to $im(L)\cap ker(T)=(0)$.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo. Thanks for spotting it.We still have $im(T) \cap ker(L) = \emptyset$

Comment: To be honest, I don't see why $0$ is not in the intersection $im(T)\cap ker(L)$ if both $L,T$ are linear.  Can can this be the case?

Comment: It always is the case

Comment: Wrote this on my phone so some errors have slipped apparently. Thanks for pointing this out. Now everything should be ok.

Comment: No worries, I feel better about my understanding now.  Also, its good to know phones are being put to good use :P

Comment: $L \circ T$ need not be surjective under these assumptions. Consider $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ given by $T(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}$ and $L:  \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ given by $L(x, y, z, w) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ w\end{bmatrix}$. It's easy to see that $T$ is injective, $L$ is surjective, and $im(T) \cap ker(L) = \{0\}$, but $L \circ T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, and so cannot be bijective.